# How can I write and share data between two different kubernetes pods (telegraf and influxdb)?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, influxdb, telegraf

I am using telegraf and influxdb for monitoring my resources.

- I will be using helm to deploy telegraf and influxdb as two different pods/deployments.
- Right now I am running a shell script within influxdb which creates auth using influx command that returns a token.
- I need to configure this token in telegraf inorder to write my metrics into influxdb.

**How can I pass my token from influxdb pod to telegraf pod ?**

*Or should I just deploy them as two containers in the same pod ?*

My requirements are as follows:

- When I deploy my microservice using helm

  1. Influxdb should be deployed first which runs the shell script to generate token.
  2. At the end deploy telegraf using the generated token.